# How to find coordinates of a country using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetchcord.py", line 18, in <module>
    coordinates = search1.find('div', {"class": "Z0LcW"}).get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd, requests as requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

datasetLocation = "D:\Projects\Corona\public\scripts\coronaprac.csv";
df = pd.read_csv(datasetLocation, 'coronaprac', engine='python')

userAgent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
    Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}
searchURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q="

for x in range(0, len(df.index)):

    if str(df.iloc[-1]) is None:
        print(str(df.iloc[x, 0]) + " | " + str(df.iloc[x, 2]) + " | " + str(df.iloc[x, 3]))

    else:
        country = df.iloc[x, 0]
        search1 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(searchURL + country + '+coordinates', 
            headers=userAgent).text, 'html.parser')
        coordinates = search1.find('div', {"class": "Z0LcW"}).get_text()
        df.loc[x, 'Coordinates'] = coordinates
        print(df.iloc[x, 0] + " | " + coordinates)
    df.to_csv(datasetLocation, index=False)
```

Comment: the error is explaining itself. read the error carefully. use `if item is not None:` or `try/except` block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get\_text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387221/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get-text)

Comment: The program's purpose is to fetch the coordinate of a country. So, do you have any other solution?